# Add interval to DateTime object prior to PHP 5.3

Tags: php, datetime

I am uploading a project to a server with an older version of PHP, which doesn't support the `add()` function of `DateTime`.

So this code:

```
$tomorrow = $today->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
```

Produces this error on the server logs:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DateTime::add()
```

I tried to find a solution which involves `strtotime` but I keep getting errors. Is there a simple workaround I can use?

Comment: strtotime() is fine. What errors do you get ?

Comment: You can use [DateTime::modify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) instead of `DateTime::add()` or `DateTime::sub()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add/subtract dates with [`DateTime::modify()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) <sup>(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)</sup>
 instead of `DateTime::add()` or `DateTime::sub()` <sup>(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)</sup>.

Instead of:

```
$tomorrow = $today->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
```

you can use:

```
$tomorrow = $today->modify('+1 day');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Create array with all dates within date span
$begin = new DateTime( $start_date );
$end = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($end_date))));
while($begin < $end) {
    $period[] = $begin->format('Y-m-d');
    $begin->modify('+1 day');
}
```

Comment: Why would you mix `strtotime` with DateTime classes?